# why am I getting a "was not declared in this scope" error?

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I get 5 errors at the following snippet of code

4 of the errors are

> expected unqualified-id before '('
>   token|

and 1 error

> 'GetEntityIterator' was not declared
>   in this scope|

`GetEntityIterator()` returns `vector<*Entity>::iterator EntityIterator`

`GetAABB()` returns an `AABB`

I can post more code if needed

```
    void Bomb::CreateExplosion(Game_Manager* EGame_Manager)
    {
    BombTexture->LoadTexture("Bomb.bmp");
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

    for(int iteration = 1; iteration <= 3; iteration++)
    {
        if(this->GetAABB()->CheckForCollision(this->GetAABB(), EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->(*GetEntityIterator())->GetAABB()) == true)//check for collision against the unbreakable blocks or player and does what is necessary for each
        {
            if(EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->(*GetEntityIterator())->GetType() == unbreakableblock)
            {
             break;
            }
            else if(EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->(*GetEntityIterator())->GetType() == player)
            {
                EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->(*GetEntityIterator())->GetLives() -= 1;
            }

        }
        else
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor4f(   1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //color red
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); //uv coordinates
            glVertex3f( -2.0f + x,2.0f  + y,  0.0f); //top left
            //----------------------------------------------------
            glColor4f(   0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //color green
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0.0 ); //uv coordinates
            glVertex3f(  2.0f + x,2.0f  + y,  0.0f); //top right
            //----------------------------------------------------
            glColor4f(   0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //color blue
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f( 2.0f + x, -2.0f + y,  0.0f); //bottom right
            //----------------------------------------------------
            glColor4f(   1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //color red
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1); //uv coordinates
            glVertex3f(-2.0f + x, -2.0f + y,  0.0f); //bottom left
        glEnd();
    }

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //disable 2d textures

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `GetEntityIterator()` returns `vector<Entity*>::iterator`?

Comment: I don't believe this to be related to your question, but did you really mean to include only the `glBegin()` in the `else`-clause, or did you accidentally leave out the `{...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of this syntax:

```
getEntityManager()->(*GetEntityIterator())
```

?

I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but the `->` operator is supposed to be followed by the name of a member of the class.

### Edit

After reading iaamilind's comment, I finally think I understand what you were trying to do. You were trying to dereference the iterator, but then you still had to dereference the pointer (`Entity*`) it returned, so the `->` operator was not enough. You're correct that you have to use parentheses and the `*` operator - but you've put them in the wrong place. This is what you should do:

```
(*EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->GetEntityIterator())->GetType()
```

Comment: Your solution cleared those errors however I get three new errors:   "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Entity**, std::vector<Entity*, std::allocator<Entity*> > > Entity_Manager::EntityIterator' is private|" "within this context|" " no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Entity**, std::vector<Entity*, std::allocator<Entity*> > >) ()'|"

Comment: Scratch that, I found out what the problem was. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks that `GetEntityIterator()` returns  pointer. Try changing it to,
`GetEntityIterator()` (i.e. remove the pointer `*` ahead of it). e.g.

```
EGame_Manager->getEntityManager()->GetEntityIterator()->GetType();
```

Also make sure that such function is declared/defined in the class.